# Android application name confusion

Tags: android

I have created an app with a full and a lite version.

Lite version:
AndroidManifest.xml
`android:label="@string/app_name"` which is SomeApp Lite.

Full version:
AndroidManifest.xml
`android:label="@string/app_name"` which is SomeApp.

Signed apks are SomeAppLite.apk and SomeApp.apk.
When I open an installer app on my phone, it shows both apps as SomeApp Lite 1.0 (ofc with the different .apk names).

Where do I miss something?

strings.xml files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="hello">SomeApp</string>
    <string name="app_name">SomeApp</string>
    <string name="widget_text">Loading...</string>
</resources>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="hello">SomeApp Lite</string>
    <string name="app_name">SomeApp Lite</string>
    <string name="widget_text">Loading...</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: Can you post your `strings.xml` files for each apk?

Comment: Do you use differnt namespaces for your apps?

Comment: I am using the same package name for both apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use different package names. if the name is the same, the phone and the Android Market consider both the same app.

Comment: Exactly what Bill said. Look in your AndroidManifest.xml for package="com.your.package" ( which usually matches your java package)

Comment: There are 2 things to say. 1. If the package names are the same, android messes up sg the strings.xml file, and this gives the problem. 2. If we use different package names, it is working fine.